# Get all possible pairs of elements in a TreeSet

Tags: java, iterator, permutation, treeset

Let's say I have a TreeSet of objects x. What I am trying to do, is iterate through all objects and get all possible pairs. So far, I have come to the code below

```
TreeSet<x> ts = new TreeSet<>();
ts.add(new x(3, true));
ts.add(new x(1, true));
ts.add(new x(2, true));
ts.add(new x(5, true));
ts.add(new x(4, true));
Iterator<x> iterator = setOfX.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("ID:"+iterator.next());
        Iterator<x> innerIterator = setOfX.tailSet(iterator.next(), true).iterator();
        while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
            int id = innerIterator.next().id;
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }
```

But the output seems to luck some of the combinations, plus it exits with an exception

```
ID:1:true
2
3
4
5
ID:3:true
4
5
ID:5:true
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Can you point towards any solution?

Comment: You mention `TreeMap` but your code is about a `TreeSet`. Which is it, map or set?

Comment: My mistake! It is a TreeSet! Fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `iterator.next()` two times. Note that this method not only gets what the iterator is currently pointing at, it also advances the iterator to the next element. Call `iterator.next()` only once per iteration and store its return value in a variable:

```
TreeSet<x> ts = new TreeSet<>();
ts.add(new x(3, true));
ts.add(new x(1, true));
ts.add(new x(2, true));
ts.add(new x(5, true));
ts.add(new x(4, true));
Iterator<x> iterator = setOfX.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // Call iterator.next() only once per iteration
        x value = iterator.next();

        System.out.println("ID:"+value);
        Iterator<x> innerIterator = setOfX.tailSet(value, true).iterator();
        while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
            int id = innerIterator.next().id;
            System.out.println(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, My solution is almost same. May be I type slowly.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing iterator.next() two times. One inside sysout other when creating innerIterator.

```
    System.out.println("ID:"+iterator.next());

    Iterator<x> innerIterator = setOfX.tailSet(iterator.next(),true).iterator();
```

**use next() once for each call of iterator.hasNext()**, you will not have Exception.

Comment: Yeah, that was it... thank you for the edit suggestion too.